# "Query_Text" seems incomplete while running from powershell using SQL cmd

Tags: powershell

I am running a script which triggers a query to fetch the worst performing SQL query for an interval of 1hr from the SQL server & also formatting the output using **"Format-Table -AutoSize"**. But the query is not printing full query rather it is printing partial.

Code Snippet:

```
function PerformerQuery {
$i=1
$number=2
do{
   $serverInstanceP = "SQLExpress2014"
   $perfQuery="
   USE [master]
   SELECT TOP 20
   total_worker_time/execution_count AS Avg_CPU_Time
   ,Execution_count
   ,total_elapsed_time/execution_count as AVG_Run_Time
   ,total_elapsed_time
   ,(SELECT SUBSTRING(text,statement_start_offset/2+1,statement_end_offset) FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle)) AS Query_Text
   FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats
    ORDER BY Avg_CPU_Time DESC
   "
   Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $serverInstanceP -Database master -Query $perfQuery -QueryTimeout 9400| Format-Table -AutoSize
   Start-Sleep -s 3
    } 
    while ($i -le $number)
}

PerformerQuery
```

Tried with **"Out-String" & "Out-Gridview"**, but the same output. Cannot use **"ft"** as it is printing the discrete data.

Please refer the screenshot as the output (added both command line output and database server output).

*Database Server output:*
[image]

*Commandline output:*
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to add `-Wrap` to the `Format-Table` and/or pipe it to `Out-String -Width 500` so it does not use the terminal width as a limit.

Comment: Not sure what the line length limit is. But there is also another issue with some versions of PS bloating up the lines. I think this is fixed in PS6. BTW: not sure if your script is very helpful to be run every 3 seconds as you will not see "newcomers", you might need to calculate "biggest increase" instead of absolute value.

Comment: Yeah, I have rectified it